# Unable to map dynamic json data to react native swiper slider using axios in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I want to pass the image URL dynamically to react-native-swiper but it gives me type error of undefined. How can I make it dynamic?  I am new to react-native So kindly help me and Thanks in advance.

I am on MacX using react native

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
import { scale } from '../../assets/css/Scaling';
import {ROOT_URL} from '../../../get_connection';


const {width} = Dimensions.get('window');

const SliderImg = props => ( 

    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: props.uri}}/>
    </View>
);

const styles = {
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',

        paddingTop: scale(15),

    },
    image: {
        flex: 1,
        width,

    }

};

 class Slider extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)


        this.state = {
            imagesSlider: ["http://burgerhut1313.in/KaptureOne/admin/upload/slider_img/slider.png","http://burgerhut1313.in/KaptureOne/admin/upload/slider_img/slider1.png","http://burgerhut1313.in/KaptureOne/admin/upload/slider_img/slider2.png"]
        }


    };

     componentDidMount(){
        this.getSliderContent();
   }
    getSliderContent() {
        // We're using axios instead of Fetch
        axios
          // The API we're requesting data from
          .get(`${ROOT_URL}/getSlider.php`)
          // Once we get a response, we'll map the API endpoints to our props
          .then(response =>
           response.data,

          )
          // Let's make sure to change the loading state to display the data
          .then(slides => {
            this.setState({
              slides: slides

            });

          })
          // We can still use the `.catch()` method since axios is promise-based
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }



    render (){

        return (
            console.log("slides state: "+this.state.slides),
            console.log("imagesSlider state: "+this.state.imagesSlider),
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <Swiper
                    autoplay
                    autoplayDelay={3}
                    height={240}
                    dotColor='#fff'
                    paginationStyle={{ bottom: scale(10) }} 
                    activeDotColor= '#0071bc'

                >

                {
                    this.state.slides.map((item, i) => <SliderImg 
                        uri={item}
                        key={i}
                    />)
                }


                </Swiper>
            </View>
        )
    }

};

export { Slider };
```

I expect to fetch the slides URL and then display it but it gives an error of undefined when I map the slides data

This shows in the console:
[image: Console error screenshot]

Comment: you can do this in 2 ways.   
1.   in setState in constructor add slides:[] or you can go with second step.
2.  {this.state.slides !== undefined && <SwiperComponent/>}

Answer (score 0):

At first render, your function is trying to do a `map()` on an undefined value, as you didn't define it in constructor. You either have to check if the values exists as array or initialize it in the constructor as array:

```
   constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        imagesSlider: ["http://burgerhut1313.in/KaptureOne/admin/upload/slider_img/slider.png","http://burgerhut1313.in/KaptureOne/admin/upload/slider_img/slider1.png","http://burgerhut1313.in/KaptureOne/admin/upload/slider_img/slider2.png"],
        slides:[]
    }
};
```